# JNI get asset filepath

Tags: android, java-native-interface, opencv3.0, android-assets

I am trying to add two .xml files with initialisation data to the APK of my Android App. In the JNI C++ Code I want to get the path to the files so I can open and read the files.

I realy need the path, because the files are opened with an OpenCV function that accesses the files.

I already have this:

(java file)

```
public native void assetLoad(AssetManager mgr);

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_vision_camera);

    assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
    assetLoad(assetManager);
}
```

(cpp file)

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_primalpond_com_sensibleopencv_vision_1camera_assetLoad(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance,
                                                        jobject mgr) {

    AAssetManager *assMgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, mgr);


}
```

Now how do I extract the two paths to the files? the files are called classifications.xml and images.xml and are locaed in the /src/assets folder

Answer (score 3):

> Now how do I extract the two paths to the files?

There is no path to the files. Assets are files on your development machine. They are not files on the filesystem of the Android device. Instead, they are entries in the APK file.

Your choices are:

- Figure out how to adapt OpenCV to work with a Java `InputStream`, `String`, or something else (so your Java code can still work with assets normally), or
- Use Java to make a copy of those files on the local filesystem (e.g., `getFilesDir()`, so OpenCV can work with those copies.